# Can I set a text color for links inside a text view?

Tags: android, textview, autolink

In Android, I'm setting the `android:autoLink` property to all for my `TextView`. Is it possible to change the color for any links that are found? (I'm not in love with the default blue.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try for `TextView` in the XML:

```
android:textColorLink="@android:color/someColor"
```

and in Java code

```
 textview.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it works

```
   android:textColorLink="/*color*/"
```